# Meaning of "mind is full of red"

Tags: meaning, phrases, vocabulary, lyrics

What does it mean (from famous song Somebody to love of Jefferson Airplane):

> When the garden flowers, baby, are dead yes
>   And your mind, your mind is so full of red

Especially "mind full of red". Is it common expression in English?

Comment: "Red" is the color of anger and, sometimes, a certain type of sadness or depression.  Also, "red" can simply mean crying a lot.  (The first part is best interpreted as reading "When the garden flowers are dead, baby," by the way.)  This is basically setting up the conditions of why you'd "want somebody to love".

Comment: Song lyrics, like poetry, use many non-standard usages, word meanings, and constructions. Different people can interpret them in different ways.

Comment: Added the lyric tag to your OP, OK?

Comment: I've always loved the song, but for me it's an impressionistic piece (*more feeling than meaning*) driven by the music, melody, and finally that refrain hook that is the song's title delivered in Grace Slick's unforgettable vocal.

Comment: Not a common expression.  Red is also the color of blood. Remember, this music was colored by the war in Vietnam.

Comment: @HotLicks sounds like an answer for me ). Could you please rewrite it, so i can accept it?

Comment: @LittleEva Surpisingly, english SE have this tag lyric! Yes, i agree that this song is very impressionistic, but i am not native speaker, so just in case i posted this question.

Comment: Baby refers to the gal being spoken to, not a small child. There's a comma between it and 'are dead'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Red" is the color of anger and, sometimes, a certain type of sadness or depression. Also, "red" can simply mean crying a lot.  It's unclear from the song which in particular is the problem, but it doesn't matter that much which, to understand the song.

Also note that the first part is best interpreted as reading "When the garden flowers are dead, baby," presumably meaning "when the joys of summer are gone" or "when something beautiful is gone" or some such.  Again, the specific meaning is not critical to understanding the song (and the lyrics are likely intentionally vague).

All this is basically setting up the conditions of why you'd "want somebody to love".

Comment: Considering what day it is (or was, yesterday), I find it rather apt to mention here that this bit has always reminded me of Valentine’s. Apart from being the colour of anger and blood, red is also the colour of hearts and love, and around Valentine’s, everything is red everywhere, so your mind is full of it. But if you don't have a date, no one will bring you flowers = the garden flowers are ‘dead’. In which case you're quite likely to want someone to love. And a bucket of ice cream.

Answer (score 2):

This is what became known as "psychedelic rock". It really doesn't need to follow the usual rules of rationality. Or grammar. Or logic. It just sounds cool.

And if "mind full of red" or "mind is full of red" is commonly (or even rarely) used, it's news to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently I'm the oldest person in the vicinity because I can tell you for certain that "red" in this context does not refer to blood, Valentine's Day, or anger. Nor is it a vague reference to something psychedelic.  Reds were (are?)* downers, typically Seconal, which some folks consider(ed)* a good-time drug.

In addition to the reference in "Somebody to Love", the Grateful Dead sang about "sweet Jane" who was "living on reds, vitamin C, and cocaine".

*No idea what the kids are up to these days.